# Constructor Injection Win8 App

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, constructor-injection

How to implement DI and IoC in Win8 App?
In windows form if I needed a form with dependencies I passed in the constructor (Constructor Injection)
But with Page how do you?
If I build a page with this constructor (

```
HomePage myPage = new HomePage (MyService1 ms, MyService2 ms))
```

then the

```
Navigate (typeof (HomePage))
```

how can I pass arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem using the `Content` of `Frame` instead of `Source` :

```
myFrame.Content = new HomePage (MyService1 ms, MyService2 ms);
```